# How do I create a path between two anchor points on different paths?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, path, pen-tool

This is a really easy question, but everything online shows me how to merge to paths together. I want to create a path between these two points, not changing their individual positions at all.
[image]

Comment: It's not possible to join those and have a closed path, because the anchor point on the right is not an end point.

Answer (score 1):

If they are both paths on the same path in the **Path Panel** OR a *single Shape layer* -- using the **Pen Tool** click one anchor point, then click the other.

If they are *separate paths* in the Paths Panel, copy one path, paste it on the other.. and then click one anchor then the other. Paths have to be the same "work path" in the Paths Panel to join them.

If they are paths on separate **Shape Layers** -- first highlight both layers in the **Layers Panel** and choose `Layer > Merge Shapes` -- *then* click one anchor then the other. You can only join paths on the *same* shape layer.

Photoshop doesn't have a any "join" features for paths like Illustrator does.

Comment: I can't select both anchor points for some reason. They are on the same path, as you can see, but it's separated into two sections. http://i.imgur.com/BZJ7goV.gifv

Comment: You don't select the anchors... you can't. You click one anchor,. then move to the end of the other path and click again... the second click is a relatively "blind" click, but it will join the paths. And you can only join **end** anchor points. That is *not* what your gif shows. Anchor points can **only** have 2 paths connected to them. **no anchor can ever have 3 connected paths**. What you are trying in that gif is just not possible.